# Convert natural language into logical formula

Tags: logic, nlp, nltk, lambda-calculus

I tried for days to write a NLTK grammar to convert simple French sentences into logical formulas. My problem can be similar with English sentences. My goal is that this grammar accepts several orders (home automation) and converts them into logical formulas. Some examples of orders:

Turn on the light:

```
exists x.(turn_on(x) & light(x))
```

Turn on the green light:

```
exists x.(turn_on(x) & light(x) & green(x))
```

Turn on the light of the kitchen

```
exists x.(turn_on(x) & light(x) & exists y.(kitchen(y) & in(x, y)))
```

In these examples, the word *turn_on* is not really a logical predicate. It will be used in the next step of my program (when it will convert this formula into another representation).

However, I have many difficulties to write the rule about possession relationship. I would like that the rule accepts an "infinite" recursion like:

- turn on the light of the kitchen (the light belongs to the kitchen in my database)
- turn on the light of the kitchen of the house (the kitchen belongs to the house in my database)
- turn on the light of the kitchen of the house of [...] (etc.)

I succeeded to convert the first sentence but not the others. Here my grammar (I translate French to English for a better understanding):

```
% start SV

SV[SEM=<?v(?sn)>] -> V[SEM=?v] SN[SEM=?sn]

SN[SEM=<?ap(?sn1, ?sn2)>] -> SN[SEM=?sn1] AP[SEM=?ap] SN[SEM=?sn2]
SN[SEM=<?ad(?n)>]         -> AD[SEM=?ad] N[SEM=?n]
SN[SEM=?n]                -> N[SEM=?n]

N[SEM=<?adj(?n)>] -> ADJ[SEM=?adj] N[SEM=?n]

V[SEM=<\P.P(\x.turn_on(x))>]  -> 'turn' 'on'

N[SEM=<\x.light(x)>]    -> 'light'
N[SEM=<\x.kitchen(x)>]  -> 'kitchen'
N[SEM=<\x.house(x)>]    -> 'house'

ADJ[SEM=<\P x.(P(x) & big(x))>]   -> 'big'
ADJ[SEM=<\P x.(P(x) & green(x))>] -> 'green'

AD[SEM=<\P Q.exists x.(P(x) & Q(x))>]         -> 'the'
AP[SEM=<\P Q R.Q(\x.P(\y.(in(y,x) & R(y))))>] -> 'of'
```

With this grammar and the order "turn on the light of the kitchen", I get:

```
exists x.(kitchen(x) & exists z1.(light(z1) & in(z1,x) & turn_on(z1)))
```

But, for the order "turn on the light of the kitchen of the house":

```
exists x.(house(x) & exists z5.(kitchen(z5) & exists z2.(light(z2) & in(z2,z5) & in(z2,x) & turn_on(z2))))
```

To be more readable, the same formula without the "exists":

```
(house(x4) & kitchen(x6) & light(x7) & in(x7,x6) & in(x7,x4) & turn_on(x7))
```

There is a problem with the "in" predicates. Indeed, I want that the light is in the kitchen and that the kitchen is in the house. However, in this case, the light is in the kitchen and in the house (yes, it's true, but I don't want that =/). Here's what I would like:

```
(house(x4) & kitchen(x6) & light(x7) & in(x7,x6) & in(x6,x4) & turn_on(x7))
                                   the difference -----^
```

I tried several methods but none of them worked... Can you help me please? I don't know if it's possible with my grammar. My knowledge on logic and lambda calcul are limited, I only just beginning to get interested in these topics.

**EDIT:**
Here is the python code that I use for my tests:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import nltk

def exec(parser, query):
    try:
        trees = list(parser.parse(query.split()))
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid query')
        return
    if len(trees) == 0:
        print('Invalid query')
        return
    print('query: %s' % query)
    print('results:')
    for t in trees:
        sem = t.label()['SEM']
        print('\t%s' % sem)
    print('')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = nltk.load_parser('./en_grammar.fcfg')
    exec(parser, 'turn on the light')
    exec(parser, 'turn on the light of the kitchen')
    exec(parser, 'turn on the light of the kitchen of the house')
```

Thanks a lot and sorry for my English.

Comment: I don't know what kind of a grammar that is and how the (controlled) NL text is parsed, but maybe you can define some kind of operator precedence for interpreting "of" – it should bind stronger to the right than to the left, in your example.

Comment: I'm using `nltk.parse.featurechart.FeatureChartParser` to use this grammar. If I change the SEM of NP rule to `?ap(?sn2, ?sn1)` and the `in(y,x)` of the AP rule to `in(x,y)`, I get this: `(light(x4) & kitchen(x7) & in(x4,x7) & house(x6) & in(x7,x6) & turn_on(x6))`. In this case, the "in" predicates are correct but `turn_on` is applied to the house =/

Comment: There should be several interpretations based on your grammar, you are seeing one of the interpretations. Would you please show the python code which produce the logical interpretation of the text?

Comment: I don't understand this law: `SN[SEM=?n]  -> N[SEM=?n]`. Do you need a noun phrase without definite article?

Comment: Before your comment, I displayed only the first tree. I modified my program to display all trees and, indeed, you're right! The second interpretation give `(house(x) & kitchen(z3) & in(z3,x) & light(z6) & in(z6,z3) & turn_on(z6))`. I edited my question to add the new version of my script. Do you know how I can modify my grammar to have only one interpretation?

For the rule that you don't understand, it is useless in this grammar but my French grammar has more rules and this one can be usefull.

Thanks a lot Medhi.

Comment: Oh! yw! I posted my answer before reading your comment! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say that an existential quantifier is the logical form of an imperative sentence. However, your question lies in another problem.

It seems that you have an ambiguous grammar. Specially when you intrepret the `x of y` with `in(x, y)` function, it is imaginable to have similar ambiguity as in second phrase:

> the light of the kitchen in the house .
>
> the ball of the kid in the yard .

1. The ball which is in the yard.
2. The kid who is the yard.

Your grammar based on your code produces these two interpretations for desired sentence:

```
query: turn on the light of the kitchen of the house
results:
    exists x.(house(x) & exists z5.(kitchen(z5) & exists z2.(light(z2) & in(z2,z5) & in(z2,x) & turn_on(z2))))
    exists x.(house(x) & exists z3.(kitchen(z3) & in(z3,x) & exists z6.(light(z6) & in(z6,z3) & turn_on(z6))))
```

In second interpretation: `house(x) & exists z3.(kitchen(z3) & in(z3,x) ...` is exact thing that you want.

**UPDATE:**

Let's try to avoid the ambiguity in chains of `x of y of z`.

One very fast solution to force `x of (y of z)` instead of `(x of y) of z` is to track the `of` usage in all noun phrases, and then force it to have no `OF` on the left side of the `of`:

```
SN[SEM=<?ap(?sn1, ?sn2)>, +OF] -> SN[SEM=?sn1, -OF] AP[SEM=?ap] SN[SEM=?sn2]
SN[SEM=<?ad(?n)>, -OF]         -> AD[SEM=?ad] N[SEM=?n]
SN[SEM=?n, -OF]                -> N[SEM=?n]
```

Comment: Yeah, I know that an existential quantifier is not the best representation of an imperative sentence. Perhaps I should just use a simple variable without quantifier? So, do you know if it's possible to write an unambiguous grammar for this use? Thanks again :D!

Comment: It is a challenge. I will try to update this post with your answer after I found the answer.

Comment: I didn't know this syntax. It's perfect! Thanks a lot Mehdi :D !